# Link in calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I built a custom ID field that concatenates some items from the list(year, ID, department). From that custom ID field i built a calculated column that will link to the actual item. This works fine until the item is edited , then the ID disappears from my custom ID, thus breaking the Link as well.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [SharePoint S.E.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)! To make it easier for others to understand the issue, can you add some images that helps describe the issue? In this case, images on what the result looks like when you first add an item, your edit screen, then the post-edit item. Are you referencing the built-in ID that's used for enumerating the list items?

Comment: Yes I am. I think I have found a fix for this by updating the workflow to run when an item is changed.

Comment: Okay, glad to know you've figured it out. You might be interested in a different feature on SharePoint that supplies a Unique Document ID to items/documents in SharePoint libraries. This supplies a link that can find your document regardless of its location on SharePoint, and regardless of the other metadata in your list. If you're interested, check out the [MS Support page here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984). Good luck!

Comment: Well it didnt fix my issue anyways